# Writing text to certain positions in a TextView

Tags: java, android, user-interface

My application has a TextView, used for showing lots of data for the user.  The data would be best represented in a structured, "semi-spreadsheet way", ie. some data would need to be always shown on topmost line of the view, some data on bottom-left corner, some on bottom-right corner, and the "middle" of my view would need to be reserved for other stuff.

As a minimum, I would thus need to reserve:

- topmost row for certain data
- bottom left corner for some
- bottom right corner for some
- the rest of my view to a rapidly changing data stream

Is there any UI component which would allow me to position my txt freely around the component, to achieve my goal?  I need to keep this view (currently TextView) as one, since I need the view to be clickable for other purposes, and dividing the area into millions of small TextViews really is not the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RelativeLayout creatively to achieve what you need. There is no specific layout that will satisfy your needs. But RelativeLayout is something i can see that would serve your purpose if used creatively.

Comment: I am pretty new to Android programming, and haven't so far seen any example of applying a specific layout "internally" to one specific UI component.  I am currently using RelativeLayout to arrange all of my app's UI components (the TextView included), but your suggestion seems to hint I could apply a specific, carefully designed RelativeLayout to the TextView I'm talking about?  Could you outline your idea a bit more?

Comment: OK. Your RelativeLayout will occupy the full screen. Then create, say 2 LinearLayout that contains the bottom right and bottom left text views. And use alignParentBottom|alignParentLeft and alignParentBottom|alignParentRight resp., for those two LinearLayouts. Then another one for default which is top left (so, no qualifiers needed for that). For remaining stuff, use alignToRightOf and alignToLeftOf so that they fit between bottom left and bottom right LinearLayouts. Or something to that effect. I think you get the idea :) If it helped, kindly accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: But I think you are suggesting I use several TextViews for this?  For the reason I gave in my question, I really want to achieve this with **one** TextView only - so really need a way to position text _inside_ my one TextView.

Comment: I see. No, i think you should rethink that approach. :) TextView is a view/widget and not a ViewGroup. Save yourself a lot of trouble by approaching your problem a different way. That would be my sincere suggestion.

Comment: OK I can see your point, harikris.  My only problem is this: if I change my app into using a (tightly grouped) set of TextViews, I would certainly achieve my goal of showing the info on the screen in a structured way.  But, how could I then define a clickable rectangle, enclosing my grouped TextViews?  Because currently my (one and only) TextView works as a clickable component as well, and I want to keep that functionality in my app.

Comment: As I read more about Android GUI design, I'm actually leaning towards using a creative combination of ViewGroup and GridLayout for my problem.  Since you gave the idea of using several views together instead of trying to achieve everything inside the TextView (which, I think, would require me to write my own extension of the TextView class, for positioning the text), I'm going to accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks :) Welcome to Android programming world.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your xml file for alinment.

```
android:gravity="left"
```

OR in java you can do

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextviewid);
textView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

For aligning view inside relative layout you can do any of this

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

Comment: This changes the alignment for the whole component and really doesn't answer to my question, which is about more complex arrangement of the output to TextView.

Comment: see the changes in my answer hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Relative layout in your layout xml file and position different textviews according to your need using align properties as described above.

Note: Android does not provide facility to write text in textview at particular position, what at most android provide is align text within textView to left/right/middle position using layout_gravity parameter, but this applies to whole text in textview.